# Segmentation fault: in tf.matmul when profiling on GPU tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, profiling

I have a segmentation fault when profiling code on GPU comming from tf.matmul. When I don't profile the code run normally.

Code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape,Dense
import numpy as np

tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
options = tf.profiler.experimental.ProfilerOptions(host_tracer_level = 3,
                                                python_tracer_level = 1,
                                                   device_tracer_level = 1)
tf.profiler.experimental.start('logdir3',options=options)

with tf.profiler.experimental.Profile('logdir'):
    # Create some tensors
    a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
    b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)


tf.profiler.experimental.stop()
```

Versions :

## nvidia-smi :

NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06
Driver Version: 450.51.06
CUDA Version: 11.0

```
# PIP LIST | grep tens
tensorboard               2.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-profile 2.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.9.0 (or 2.11)                 pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.32.0                   pypi_0    pypi

# conda list
cuda-nvcc                 12.1.66                       0    nvidia
cudatoolkit               11.2.2               he111cf0_8    nvidia
cudnn                     8.1.0.77             h90431f1_0    conda-forge
```